# Windows 64 MSYS2 MSYS GCC Fatal Error: Cannot execute 'cc1'

Tags: c++, c, msys2

I keep getting the following error message when trying to execute a simple Hello World program.

```
gcc: fatal error: cannot execute 'cc1': CreateProcess: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling MSYS2 twice. I think it may have something to do with the paths I have set. I have the following paths set:

C:\msys64\usr\bin

C:\msys64\mingw64\bin

A similar error is returned when I try and run a Hello world program using C++:

```
g++: fatal error: cannot execute 'cc1plus': CreateProcess: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

Comment: `cc1` is usually not in $PATH - rather, it is stored at an internal location that the compiler knows about. On Linux it is `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/cc1` (where 8 is the versions, and you'll also have to replace the triple at least) as found by `gcc -print-prog-name=cc1`. You should look where cc1.exe actually is vs where the compiler thinks it should be.

Comment: [Process monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) can help you track down where cc1 is expected to be.

Answer (score 2):

It is an issue with cc1.exe being flagged by several antivirus programs, including Windows Defender. MSYS2 developers have since updated the package and many users also reported the issue to Microsoft.

Please update the packages with:

```
pacman -Syu
```

Not sure if the issue is resolved for all antivirus programs, but I can confirm it is for Symantec.

Here is the issue on github for reference: https://github.com/msys2/MINGW-packages/issues/10295.

---

Comment: tysm this actually work with rtools4

Answer (score 0):

Uninstalled and Reinstalled. Skipped the update files steps recommended on: https://www.msys2.org/. This fixed the issue