# Gcc can't find Temp

Tags: c, gcc

I am a beginner and I use Gcc compiler. At least, I used, because it suddenly stopped working giving me this error

```
cc1: fatal error: cannot open '/c/Users/UTENTE~1/AppData/Local/Temp/cc8t2W16.s' for writing: No such file or directory
```

where "UTENTE" means "USER" and the .s file changes every time. This result is given to every code I tried to compile, the command was

> gcc filename.c

and my OS is Windows. Can anyone help me? Maybe in really simple language, because I am very new...

Comment: Does that directory exist?

Comment: The compiler cannot find a "s" file in that folder, but yes, Temp exists.

Comment: Are you using MinGW?

Comment: No, I am using msys. Also, thank you for your time and sorry for not specifying enough and for the time it takes me to answer...

Comment: Does the following command work? `gcc --version`

Comment: Yes, the output was that: `gcc (GCC) 11.2.0
Copyright (C) 2021 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.`

Comment: You probably need to reinstall GCC. https://github.com/msys2/MINGW-packages/issues/8107 https://stackoverflow.com/q/11912878/4688321 https://stackoverflow.com/q/70283495/4688321

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I already reinstalled by executing `#pacman -s base-devel` and `#pacman -s gcc` but maybe you mean something else. I'll also try to compile from the msys window and not the command prompt window.